# Should I use synchronization for visibility of a single pointer?

Tags: go

As per [the reference](https://go.dev/ref/mem), it says

> Otherwise, each read of a single-word-sized or sub-word-sized memory location must observe a value actually written to that location (perhaps by a concurrent executing goroutine) and not yet overwritten.

Since a pointer is word-sized, does that mean synchronization is not necessary for mere purpose of visiblity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, **visibility** means that when one *goroutine* writes to a variable, other *goroutines* see the change. So, visibility requires synchronization. Otherwise a reading *goroutine* will possibly see a stale (not updated) value of the variable.

Comment: Forgive me if I'm wrong, but that case is against `and not yet overwritten`. The reference does say it *must* observe the aforementioned value.

Comment: The way I understand the sentence, is that "not yet overwritten" means the value that was written to the variable in the past but not the latest value.

Comment: I think you're right. I misread the sentence. Thanks!